# Not show measure by permission

Tags: security, ssas, cube

The context

I had a measure calculated than review the source dimension, by role I restrict the source dimension. How the measure can be calculate if the user doesn´t had access to the dimension?

Comment: Please show your role settings. How dimension restriction was implemented? "Denied member set" or any other case? What is a setting of "Enable Visual Totals"?

Answer (score 0):

I delete the role and rebuild from zero, and the measure work fine